# Django: How can I set form instance as a variable which was defined inside the HTML page?

Tags: django

So my blog has posts and comments.
I want the users to be able to edit the comment through a BOOTSTRAP MODAL that opens inside the same page when you click the edit button.
But I'm actually facing a problem, now there is a for loop inside the html page where I defined the comment variable :

```
 {%for comment in comments%}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data- 
       target="#Edit{{comment.id}}Modal">edit test</button> 
 {%endfor%}
```

Code at Views.py :

```
post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
comments = post.comment_set.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    editcommentform = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
    if editcommentform.is_valid():
        editcommentform.save()
else:
    editcommentform = CommentForm(instance=comment)
```

now in my views.py I cannot actually set the instance to comment because I get an error of "comment is not defined"

**My question is how can i set the instance to comment while it's only defined inside the for loop in the HTML page?**

Sorry if it may sound unclear or weird, I am new to the field.

Answer (score 0):

You put a name for the button and use it in the view function

```
    {%for comment in comments%}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data- 
       target="#Edit{{comment.id}}Modal" name={{comment.id}}>edit test</button> 
    {%endfor%}
```

then you can make the function takes comment_id as an argument and use it to update the db